# PGP File Decryption

Tags: c#, process, pgp

Need some help with pgp file decryption
anyone have an idea how to do it in c#?
I have it implemented through `process.start ("cmd.exe", command)`
but its not doing anything other than openning the `C:\Windows\System32\IISExpress>`
the command line not getting executed,

any help is appreciated.

Code Snippet:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "pgp --decrypt " + inputfile+ " -r \"inputphrase\" --passphrase     \"passphrase\" --output " + outputfile+ ".txt";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Please suggest if there is way to achieve this.

Comment: how is "cmd.exe" related to IISExpress?

Comment: And what command are you executing?

Comment: I added code im using to decrypt pgp file and save it in txt format. Thank you for help.

Comment: Have a look at [this bouncycastle tutorial for decrypting OpenPGP stuff in C#](http://rafayal.blogspot.de/2009/06/pgp-decryption-with-c.html). No need for calling native processes.

Answer (score 1):

The better way would be to use PGP (or OpenPGP, which is the same) library for C#/.NET.
There are free and opensource ones (like Bouncycastle), but they lack support, examples, etc.
Also there are better supported commercial libraries (like SecureBlackbox), but they cost some money.